# Ardalis Specification Repository can be injected but when call any method, get object reference error

Tags: repository-pattern, .net-7.0, ardalis-specification

I use Ardalis Specifications with Entity Framework. I wrote my app in .NET 7 and I use an onion architecture with mediatr pattern. I have a generic interface `IRepository` and I define it as scoped.

When I inject this variable is not null but when I use any method of repository then I got an error

> Object reference set not an instance of an object

I created an issue on GitHub repository but Stackoverflow users are much more responsive than GitHub issue checker users, so if you look at it, I will appreciate it.

Link: [Ardalis Specification Github Issues](https://github.com/ardalis/Specification/issues/339)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't pass tenant so if table multitenant and you did not pass tenantId to application, then this error raised. Problem solved when tenantId passed.